# Retrieving form groups using freeASPUpload

Tags: forms, asp-classic, vbscript

Sorry for the noob question. Is it possible to replicate something like this when using freeASPUpload which uses enctype="multipart/form-data" encrypted forms.

```
For i = 1 to Request.Form.Count
   Response.Write(Request.Form.Key(i))
   Response.Write(Request.Form.Item(i))
Next
```

I know I can access individual form fields using something like Upload.Form("Name"), but I'm trying to work out how to access all the form as a group.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but this should work for you...

```
For each x in Upload.FormElements
   Response.Write(x) 
   Response.Write(Upload.Form(x)) 
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't have a upload setup to check right now, but wont this work ?

```
For each x in Upload.Form
   Response.Write(x)
   Response.Write(Upload.Form(x))
Next
```

Here's the link for the component:http://www.freeaspupload.net/freeaspupload/documentation.asp

Comment: No. Unfortunately that just hangs. No error message at all. Thanks for the response.